# Google Scripts - Unexplained Error when using multiple functions

Tags: function, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a google automation for a spreadsheet I'm working with. I have gotten the code to a point where it works if I have two separate functions and run it separately, but I cannot find success with joining the functions. When completed separately I end up with the resulting data structured how I need it, but the different ways I've tried to connect them always ends with a blank workbook.

```
function Part_1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Add formulas to Correct Columns
  spreadsheet.getRange('K1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('K1:K'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=RIGHT(C1,2)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('L1:L'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('M1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=D1');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('M1:M'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('N1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=CONCATENATE(E1," ",F1)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('N1:N'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('O1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=G1');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('O1:O'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
// Copy values from columns K to O to columns P to T
  spreadsheet.getRange('K1:O').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('P1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}

function Part_2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('P1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('K1:O').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:O').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('O1'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('P1').activate();
  spreadsheet.deleteColumns(1,15)
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C')
  range.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy');
};
```

I have tried adding the following to the end of part_1:
Adding a line part_2();
Copying the entire part_2 code
Adding code from part_2 line by line, but even with just a few line the paste never happens

Comment: Use of ranges like "A:O" are not a good idea with Google Apps Script.  They usually generate a lost of nulls add a starting row and sheet.getLastRow() and you're better off.   And I don't  know about other developers but I don't even bother reading code that's written like it came from a macro recorder.   I would recommend greatly reducing your use of activate and getActive anything.